# passing specific site traffic from different dns using coredns

Tags: dns, coredns

I have coredns setup at home,

whenever I am connected to my office via vpn from office macbook It uses DNS that gets setup by vpn software and I do not have privilages to change that.

so is it possible that if I have url request to office website money.rediff.com it should go from directly via office DNS but for everything else it should go from my dns server at home.

this is my current coredns config Corefile.

$ /etc/coredns/Corefile

```
(global) {
    log
    errors
    cache 86400 {
      prefetch 5 10m 10%
    }
    dnssec
  }


.:5335 {
    import global

    forward . tls://1.1.1.1 {
    tls_servername cloudflare-dns.com
    health_check 10s
   }
    loop
    reload
        
}

tls://.:853 {
  tls /etc/coredns/cert.pem /etc/coredns/key.pem
  forward . 192.168.0.12:5335
}
```